# notifyDataSetChanged not updating view

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I am using viewModel in recycler view, but its not updating only if I enter and exist screen not in screen itself:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(RideDataViewModel::class.java)

    rideList.adapter = MyRideListItemRecyclerViewAdapter(viewModel.rides.value!!, object : OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClicked(ride: RideEntity) {
            viewModel.setRide(ride)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.rideDataFragment)
        }
    })

    viewModel.rides.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {

        if (it.isNotEmpty()) 
        {
            no_rides.visibility = View.GONE
           rideList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged() //Function called but no visible data
        }
        else
        {
            no_rides.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    })


    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.setRides(DataBaseHelper.getAllRidesFromDB())
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class RideDataViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
        var rides= MutableLiveData<List<RideEntity>>(listOf())
        fun setRides(item: List<RideEntity>) {
            rides.postValue(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: You observe `viewModel.rides` and do nothing with the result, you didn't updated the adapter. or maybe you think that `viewModel.rides.value` in adapter's constructor have same reference as the result in `viewModel.rides.observe` and should contain the new list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show your adapters code, but you need to set the adapters underlying data/list using the `it` reference before calling `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
if (it.isNotEmpty())  {
    no_rides.visibility = View.GONE
    rideList.adapter!!.data = it // something similar to set the list in your adapter to the new values
    rideList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged() //Function called but no visible data
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am setting the data in the constructor:
MyRideListItemRecyclerViewAdapter(viewModel.rides.value!!

Also the code works when navigating to new fragment and back to this one

Comment: @Dim That data is most likely empty at the time. It's only given a value when you observe it and `setRides` is called (which you only call after creating the adapter). This can be verified by using a breakpoint and determining the value of `viewModel.rides.value!!` when you instantiate your adapter. If it has a value, I'd then suggest updating your question with your adapter code

Comment: When I instantiate the adapter the  viewModel.rides.value is empty, you right. But the I fill it and I call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @Dim Exactly, so you need to update the adapter when your observer fires with the new data just like my answer shows. The value you passed in to your adapter when you instantiate it doesn't change, how will it? It's not magic lol, you need to set your adapter with new data i.e. update the underlying list of the adapter and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 1):

Where are you setting the list on your adapter? In your LiveData observer you're only calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, which will only make the RecyclerView redraw the items, but you don't set the items first so it has nothing to redraw.

I don't know how your adapter looks, but something along the lines of the code below should make it update

```
if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
    no_rides.visibility = View.GONE
    rideList.adapter!!.list = it              // Update the list in the adapter
    rideList.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged() // Now this will have something to draw
}
```